# How to get Current working directory in the Google Compute Engine Python

Tags: python-3.x, flask, google-app-engine, google-compute-engine

Building an Web Application in the Google Compute Engine. Added the .json files in the **/home/project** directory and have python scripts in the **/home/project/gsuite/pscript.py**

How can i access the .json file that is present in the /home/project folder. I tried using **os.getcwd()** inside **/home/project/gsuite/pscript.py** file, but its returning as '/workspace'

Any help is appreciated!.

Thanks & Regards,
Prashant

Comment: Edit your question and show your code and the command that runs the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can jsut open the file like

```
path = "/home/project/data.json"
with open(path) as file:
   file.read()
```

if it won't work then you should try to change your working Dir

```
os.chdir(dir_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

After searching a lot, found some google documentation. We wont be able to read or write to files in the Google App Engine. For that we need use Google Storage to read and write to file. If the file is temporary we can use the `/tmp` directory.

Google Documentation that explains about this. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/using-temp-files

Comment: Your question is tagged **google-compute-engine** App Engine is a different service/product that has different features and requirements.

Comment: We will be deploying the Web Application in Google Compute Engine. Inside compute engine, we use gcloud app deploy. So added the tag 'google-compute-engine'

Comment: Your question should be tagged based upon the question asked.